# Search result - 500 error

Tags: 7, search

My Drupal 7 websites started to throw 500 error when I see the search result page.

## How to replicate:

When I enter any keyword and hit search button then I see this URL "http://www.website.com/search/node/keyword" and I see the broken page layout with no result. and I see the error "500 server error" on browser console. Please see the screenshot:
https://snag.gy/VsoQqj.jpg

Please see the screenshot of search settings and permissions

**Search Module:**
https://snag.gy/LNBciP.jpg

**Search Permission:**
https://snag.gy/EGMIfc.jpg

**Search Settings:**
https://snag.gy/7yGmQ6.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to say without seeing an actual error.

Do you have see this url: "http://www.website.com/search/node/keyword" or was this just to give an example? If you see that url, I supposed that you see this in an ajax call somewhere since you would get a 404 and not a 500 error. If you see this error, check in your settings.php file if you have a base_url variable set to www.website.com.

Go in /admin/reports/dblog and chec if you get a more detailed error message.